# MATLAB's "logical indexing" in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation

```
% MATLAB code
A=reshape(1:16,4,[])'
k=logical([1 0 0 1; 0 1 1 0; 0 1 1 0;1 0 0 1 ])
A(k)=5-A(k)
%{
 4     2     3     1
 5    -1    -2     8
 9    -5    -6    12
-8    14    15   -11
%}
```

I need *Mathematica* code that works like the MATLAB code above. Is there a easy way do this?

```
A = Range[16]~Partition~4
k = {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}}
A[[k]] = 5 - A[[k]]
```

**Updated**:

```
fA = Flatten[A];
p = Flatten@Position[Flatten@k, 1];
fA[[p]] = 5 - fA[[p]];
Partition[fA, 4]

(*{{4, 2, 3, 1}, {5, -1, -2, 8}, {9, -5, -6, 12}, {-8, 14, 15, -11}}*)
```

Comment: You will get the answer about week earlier if you describe what do you want instead of posting code from other language. No to mention that research effort will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, I want to help but I have no clue what's in the first code block :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
A = Range[16]~Partition~4;
k = {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}};
A = 5 k + A (1 - 2 k)
```

> {{4, 2, 3, 1}, {5, -1, -2, 8}, {9, -5, -6, 12}, {-8, 14, 15, -11}}

Comment: Nice solution, but to me, at least, this is clearer if it is written as `(5 k - A) (2 k - 1)`

Answer (score 4):

As best as I can tell, the `logical` function in Matlab only applies the operation if the indicator matrix (in this case `k`) contains a `1` at the corresponding position.

So you could get the same result using something like this:

```
MapThread[If[#2 == 1, 5 - #1, #1] &, {A, k}, 2]

(* {{4, 2, 3, 1}, {5, -1, -2, 8}, {9, -5, -6, 12}, {-8, 14, 15, -11}} *)
```